# How to debug an "Error: Script error. (:0)" from Mocha?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js

I have a [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) end to end test that consistently fails with this error message:

> Error: Script error. (:0)

[image]

Cypress is built on top of [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and the Cypress support team have indicated [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4717#issuecomment-511676262) that this error originates from Mocha itself in response to a failed  async operation in my app code.

I've tried using the Chrome developer tools to find the failed operation in my code but could not find it.

Is there some way I can hook into Mocha with error handling code (listeners?) that can show me where the error originates in my code? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in Cypress GitHub issue [#4717](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4717) I've learned that:

1. The error above indicates that an error was thrown from a "3rd party" script in the application code, caught by Cypress and rethrown with the ":0" error message.
2. There is a bug in Cypress ([#987](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/987)) in that Cypress is unable, at the moment, to catch such errors in its global error handlers/hooks.
3. There's a workaround which at least enables one to see the underlying error, instead of the ":0" error:

   - Set the `"chromeWebSecurity"` setting in `cypress.json` to `false`.

Comment: I got the similar error with much less message like
Error: Script error. (:0)